# Jmeter Regex extractor, specific

Tags: regex, jmeter

I have a response within Jmeter in the form of

r.handleCallback("46","0",["","0","1","2","3"]);

What REGEX can I use to extract just the 0 , 1, 2, or 3 from this string?

I tried this

.*?\"0\".*?(\"3\")

but this mathces = r.handleCallback("46","0",["","0","1","2","3

and I do not want the preceding string of text nor do I want my target element {0,1,2,3} to be encoding into the REGEX.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure this will work in jmeter, but you can try it [`(?:\[.*?|\G(?!\A))(?:,?"(\d+)")`](https://regex101.com/r/aBgX0P/1)

Comment: thanks, but no, this syntax isn't picking up anything in Jmeter.

Comment: I just got this working [^".*?\"](\".*?\") but it goes through 46 , 0 , 0 , 1, 2, 3.... but I want it to start at the "0" within the [

Comment: Do you want each value in a different variable?

Comment: yes. so setting the match number will yield 0 , 1, 2, 3... Thinking about this more... i think the brackets start a set with the first element being null... thats why it's the ""... so the second match may start yield the 0, and the third match will yield the 1

Comment: You can use this `\["","(.+?)","(.+?)","(.+?)","(.+?)"` and refer to them like this ${MyVar_g1}(holds the value **0**) ${MyVar_g2} (holds the value **1**) and so on.

Comment: Thanks, This is pretty good. I was just reading some of the documentation about parsing the groups.... but I'm not sure if this will work for me... In this scenario, I have the 4 elements I'm searching for, and you have that syntax for the 4 groupings of (.+?) but I'm not always going to be searching through 4 elements, (it may be more or less) so I think i need it be more general

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure your Regular Expression Extractor as follows:

- Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `foo`
- Regular Expression: `(\d+)(?=(?:(?!\[).)*\])`
- Template: `$1$`
- Match No: `-1`

You will get the following JMeter Variables generated:

```
foo_1=0
foo_2=1
foo_3=2
foo_4=3
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Regex Demo]

References:

- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)

Comment: Hi Thanks, This works just about what I was looking for. I had to change the /d to /w to accommodate for alphanumeric. I'm trying to tinker with it a little bit more but is there a way to capture the internal elements when they are sentences such as: r.handleCallback("46","0",["","foo bar one","foo bar 2","foo bar 3","foo bar 4"]);